# JS/React: How to truncate text with an icon instead of ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, truncate

How to truncate text with JS/React, and replace the end of the line with a custom SVG icon instead of the CSS default ellipsis (...)?

Example situation:

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #90e4ff;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  The text here fits.
</div>

<div class="container">
  This text here is way too long and certainly doesn't fit.
</div>
```

The output in the second div with the too long text is: `This text here is way...`

But the desired output would be: `This text here is way<CustomIcon>`

Comment: what i think u should do is a conditional rendering of your `<CustomIcon>`, if the text is too long then render it otherwise u don't

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the good question:)
By CSS only you cannot use an icon. I tried to think out a solution with JS. As you can see if the background of the SVG is transparent, the text below is visible. So better to use white background to cover the text.

Another important thing is that you need to use `span`s because `div`s have default width of 100%.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
        
        for (let i=0; i< containers.length; i++) {
           
            if (containers[i].offsetWidth > 150) {
                containers[i].style.width = "150px";
                containers[i].style.setProperty('--height', '20px');
                containers[i].style.setProperty('--width', '20px');
                
            }
        }
```

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background: #90e4ff;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    width: var(--width, 0);
    height: var(--height, 0);
    background: url("https://www.svgrepo.com/show/5044/heart.svg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<span class="container"> The text here.</span>
<span class="container"> This text here is way too long and certainly doesn't fit.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems to mostly do the trick. One problem is that the icon can cut off letters in the middle which is quite unsightly. I played around with offsetting its pixels. to work around this. It's not quite perfect as the pixels have to be configured depending on the element length, icon size, and font size. The distance from the last shown letter to the icon is not constant.

Here is a jsfiddle I played around with: https://jsfiddle.net/caenf0L2/25/

Comment: Yes, I faced the problem with the truncated word. Unfortunately I cannot think out a way to check if a word is half visible and half hidden.

Comment: I have checked, `ellipsis` also truncates the words.